# How I can set appropriate configuration for each WMTS layer with EPSG:4326 (automatically in openLayers v6)?

Tags: openlayers, wmts

When I want to add my WMTS layer via this [method](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html) (how to manually create the configuration for accessing a WMTS.) in OpenLayers sometimes I get 400 (Bad Request) error from GeoServer 2.18.0 and sometimes it work's fine without error!,This is becasue extent, In same area I must change extent manually for each layer! each time I will add,I found out OpenLayers can get correct and appropriate configuration for each layer dynamically via GetCapablities response this [link](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html) and then I changed my code based on OpenLayers document, but I don't know why I still get this 400 (bad request) error? How I can get correct configuaration and extent coordinate for each WMTS layer automatically?

```
    var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities';
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities',{
         method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
       
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' +btoa(`${geoUserName}:${geoPass}`),
            'Content-Type':'text/html',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            
        },
      
      
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(data) {
      var result = parser.read(data);
      var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
        layer: `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`, //`${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`
        matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
     
      });

       console.log('options', options);
         var wmtsLayers=[
        new ol.layer.Tile({
         
           source: new ol.source.WMTS(options),
           opacity: 1,
    
        })
      ];
})
```

this is my [WMTS getcapabilities response](https://file.io/bwZubAQqbm1c)

SysInfo:Debian 10 x64,OpenLayers V6, GeoServer 2.18.0

[image]

Comment: If you need authorization for the capabilities do you also need it for the tiles?

Comment: hmm, may be it is not necessary, However I did change my code again but I got same result https://pastebin.pl/view/70d4d010, and I got bad request error message

Comment: if I add   format: 'image/png', I can see my map but I'll get that error!

Comment: `optionsFromCapabilities` does not handle `tileLoadFunction`, you would need to set `options.tileLoadFunction = function(tile, src){...};` after the call.

Comment: What other formats does the capabilities support?

Comment: it seems only png, I didn't see my layer when I did choose image/gif and when I select image/jpeg I got a white square! https://imgur.com/a/W0icaH2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116460/discussion-between-predatorx-and-mike).